# inserting array with Codeigniter active records

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have array with checkboxes values, and id value. Checkboxes can have many values, otherwise id is only one. My array is `$data2`, print_r:

```
Array ( 
  [checkbox] => Array ( 
     [0] => 1 
     [1] => 2 
     [2] => 3 
     [3] => 4 
     [4] => 8 
     [5] => 9 
     [6] => 10 
     [7] => 21 
  ) 
  [id] => 8 
)
```

Code in model is

```
function checkboxes($data2)
    {
        foreach($data2->result() as $row)
        {
            $data= array(
                  'story'=> $row->checkbox,
                  'id'=>$row->id
                );
               $this->db->insert('stories_to_categories',$data);
        }

    }
```

Problem is because i have array in array can someone help me to insert this code into db?

also i wanna have same number ids and checkboxes inserted, for example 3 id with value 1 and 3 checkboxes values

Comment: you have to insert the data variable into the database am i right so the second one is wrong because you are storing values in data variable and that you are passing the whole object data2 to the insert function which is wrong

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  What is $data2 ?   Why does it have a result() i don't see that in your original array.

Comment: let be more focused i am editing the question for better understand ChrisG are you agree

Comment: i print_r data array where is problem, u see structure

Comment: ok what's the error you are seeing

Comment: cant use... on object

Comment: i like nobs wich vote down cuz they do not know answer

Comment: You can't insert an array into a field in MySQL.  You can insert a string.  You can do `implode(',', $row->checkbox)` which will save it comma-separated.

Comment: So, `$data2` is an array?  Then why do you have `->result()`?  That means `$data2` is actually a CodeIgniter query object.  So, is that print_r actually `$row`?

Comment: ok got your problem now i am posting a dummy answer answer which might be helpful for you i just created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Dummy answer which will clear your concept that how multidimensional arrays workout in the codeigniter first of all when you are working with multidimensional so you need a key for tracking up your record which record belong to which key so it can be helpful for fetching values so far i have created a simple dummy program specially for you and have also worked in your code as well so you might like my effort as well as i hope your problem will get solved .Also check out the php manual and documentation which will make you more clear about multidimensional arrays [Multidimensional array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as well as i have use function `sizeof()` this function is use for to measure the size of an object either its self created or database object it help in measurement here is the documentation link follow along to check how can we use that [sizeof documentation](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php).

Here is the dummy code.

```
$section = array( 'Clients'=>array('pepsi','cocacola','sevenup'),
    'Services'=>array('Web Design','Graphic Design','DataMigration'),
    'Techonologies'=>array('codeigniter','postgresql','ubuntu')
    );  

      $i=0;
      foreach($section as $key => $row)
      {
          //taking up specific value
          echo $section['Techonologies'][0];
          echo '<pre>';
          //checking the size of the key in array Clients is a key and it has 3 values
          while($i<sizeof($row))
          {
              echo $row[$i].'<br/>';
              $i++; 
          }
          $i=0;
        echo '</pre>';
      }

         echo '<pre>';
          print_r($section);
          echo '</pre>';

    }
```

Here is your code i hope it may help you out from the trouble .

```
function checkboxes($data2)
    {
        $i=0;
        $data=$data2->result();
        foreach($data as $key => $row)
        {
            while($i<sizeof($row))
            {
            $data= array(
                  'story'=> $row[$i],
                  'id'=>$data['id'][0]
                );
               $this->db->insert('stories_to_categories',$data);
               $i++;
            }
        }

    }
```